# Pass a form field to a URL

Tags: forms, url, dynamic

I am not a developer but have been asked to integrate Paymate 'pay now' buttons [into a website](http://www.whitewreath.com/donate--shop).

[Paymate has an ajax form to generate the code](http://www2.paymate.com/pm/default.asp?title=Website-and-Cart-Integration&contentID=68) which is in the form:

```
<a onclick="self.name = 'parent';" target="_blank"
    href="https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?mid=<username>&amt=<amount>&ref=<reference>">

    <img src="https://www.paymate.com/images/ebay/paymate_accepted_logo_88x31.gif"
        border="0" alt="Pay with Paymate Express">
</a>
```

`username`, `amount` & `reference` are all variables input into Paymate's link generating form to generate a live link to paste into the source code.

My problem is that there are two items to be sold that come in variable multiple quantities.

I need to produce a form field which accepts a number, and on entering this number, the URL of the Paymate button needs to be altered dynamically, so that amt is the correct figure.  e.g. 25 items @ 3.50 each.

I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript libraries (such as jQuery, Prototype, RightJS, etc.)?

Comment: The website uses a paid template, which uses two JS files:
http://www.whitewreath.com/media/system/js/mootools.js
http://www.whitewreath.com/media/system/js/caption.js

Comment: If this is a one-off issue, and not the first step on your path to learning to do web development, have you considered just paying the nearest developer ~$50 to take a half hour to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a very good cause.  I've produced something using jQuery which hopefully you could adapt to your purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="product1" action="#">
      <div>Price per item: <span class="price">3.50</span></div>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <select name="quantity" class="quantity">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <div>
        Order value: AUD$<span class="order">3.50</span> <i>including AUD$8.00 postage</i>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="demonstration" />
      <input type="hidden" class="amt" name="amt" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="product1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="AUD" />
      <input type="hidden" name="amt_editable" value="N" />
      <img class="submit" src="https://www.paymate.com/images/ebay/paymate_accepted_logo_88x31.gif" border="0" alt="Pay with Paymate Express" />
    </form>

    <hr />

    <form id="product2" action="#">
      <div>Price per item: <span class="price">5.00</span></div>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <select name="quantity" class="quantity">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <div>
        Order value: AUD$<span class="order">5.00</span> <i>including AUD$8.00 postage</i>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="demonstration" />
      <input type="hidden" class="amt" name="amt" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="product2" />
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="AUD" />
      <input type="hidden" name="amt_editable" value="N" />
      <img class="submit" src="https://www.paymate.com/images/ebay/paymate_accepted_logo_88x31.gif"
           border="0" alt="Pay with Paymate Express" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var paymentUrl = "https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?";
    var postage = 8;


    jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    asset("#product1");
    asset("#product2");

    function asset(product){

        $(product + " input.quantity").val("1");

        var price = $(product + " .price").text();

        $(product + " .quantity").change(function () {
             var val = "";
             var order = 0;
             $(product + " select.quantity option:selected").each(function () {
                   val += $(this).text();
                   order = ((val * price) + postage).toFixed(2);
                   $(product + " span.order").text(order);
                   $(product + " .amt").val(order)
              });
        });

        $(product + " .submit").click(function() {
               var params = $(product).serialize();
               // alert(paymentUrl + params);
               // Go to page
               window.location.href = paymentUrl + params;

        });
     }

});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Update**: using text field instead of select drop down.  I've added a little bit of validation so that it checks if the value supplied is actually numeric.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="product1" action="#">
      <div>Price per item: <span class="price">3.50</span></div>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" />
      <div>
        Order value: AUD$<span class="order">3.50</span> <i>including AUD$8.00 postage</i>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="demonstration" />
      <input type="hidden" class="amt" name="amt" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="product1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="AUD" />
      <input type="hidden" name="amt_editable" value="N" />
      <img class="submit" src="https://www.paymate.com/images/ebay/paymate_accepted_logo_88x31.gif" border="0" alt="Pay with Paymate Express" />
    </form>

    <hr />

    <form id="product2" action="#">
      <div>Price per item: <span class="price">5.00</span></div>
      <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" />
      <div>
        Order value: AUD$<span class="order">5.00</span> <i>including AUD$8.00 postage</i>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="demonstration" />
      <input type="hidden" class="amt" name="amt" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="product2" />
      <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="AUD" />
      <input type="hidden" name="amt_editable" value="N" />
      <img class="submit" src="https://www.paymate.com/images/ebay/paymate_accepted_logo_88x31.gif"
           border="0" alt="Pay with Paymate Express" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var paymentUrl = "https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?";
    var postage = 8;

    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    asset("#product1");
    asset("#product2");

    function asset(product){

        $(product + " input.quantity").val("1");

        var price = $(product + " .price").text();

        $(product + " .quantity").keyup(function () {
             var order = 0;
             var val = $(product + " input.quantity").first().val();
             if($.isNumeric(val)){
                order = ((val * price) + postage).toFixed(2);
                $(product + " span.order").text(order);
                $(product + " .amt").val(order);
             }
        });

        $(product + " .submit").click(function() {
               var val = $(product + " input.quantity").first().val();
               if($.isNumeric(val)){
                  var params = $(product).serialize();
                  // Go to page
                  window.location.href = paymentUrl + params;
               }
        });
     }

     });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you think you could change the select drop down box into a text field where customers enter their desired number of items?

Comment: I've added a version that uses a text field.  The select drop down is often used because you can more carefully control what the user supplies.  I chose to support 1-5 but you can easily extend this.  Amazon uses the select drop down on their site, typically they have a range of 1-1000 (I appreciate that Amazon hasn't really made it big in the antipodes! ;))

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you Mark.  Amazon might flow into the antipodes one day!...  :-)

Comment: I still can't get this to work.  Can you see what is wrong?  http://www.whitewreath.com/donate-shop

Comment: Hi Steve,  You are using multiple JS libraries on your page (e.g. mootools and jQuery).  You therefore need to modify the jQuery JavaScript by adding a "noConflict" and then wrap the JavaScript as edited above.  You also don't yet have the "price" identified with a span with class price.  Hope this helps, I'm away from computer for few days now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need something more complicated than a form with method=GET ? A GET form will take all of its inputs and stick them in the url of its action, very similar to what you're asking for.

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment">
Username: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="40" name="mid"> <br />
Amount: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="40" name="amt"> <br />
Reference: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="40" name="ref"> <br />

<input type="submit" value="Pay Now"> 
</form>
```

Comment: I also need an image wrapped around by the URL in an A tag, so that the result is a click-able image.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark mentioned, you basically have to set up the calculations yourself prior to sending to Paymate because they don't offer a built-in solution for you.

If you're not comfortable with programming, just switch the website over to [Paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_wp_standard_overview) which is much quicker to get setup.

Comment: Thanks Douglas.  The website owner chose Paymate as their fees are less than Paypal's.